# How to fix WordPress htaccess file?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I was making changes to the htaccess file in wordpress using a plugin called SEO and I made a mistake saving the wrong information into the file... now WP won't let me log in and the site is down: decisivesecurity.com.au

What should I do? Do I need to go into the c-panel and delete the htaccess file and put in a new one?

Comment: Also--my manager just told me that this won't work because the parent wp-plugin needs different code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace it with the default WP htaccess file, verify it is working again then start over.

http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Comment: so I copy and past:

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

into a file called .htaccess and load it into my root directory where the old one is?

Comment: You can also delete the .htaccess file entirely - you'll be able to log in and set permalinks, etc. That might be the easiest way to start.